# Filtering two tags in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I have setup my blog in a way that there are three categories i.e, News, Insight and Comment.
Also I have created some tags forexample: Mental Health, Wellness, Clinics, Regulation, Technology and Research.
I have also setup the wordpress default filter that uses permalink to filter out blogs i.e,
/tag/mental-health

But this filter has a drawback, I can only filter by one tag at a time.

Explaining further the requirement is that there are two types within tags,
Topic and themes
if I arrange it respectively
Topic > Mental Health, Wellness, Clinics
Theme > Regulation, Technology, Research

So on the frontend it looks like two dropdowns Topics and themes, User should be able to select one from both, not two from one so this is another condition.

I am expecting to make a custom parmalink query forexample: /?tags=[topic=wellness]&[theme=research]
and a custom query that is in functions.php runs and filters out the blogs displayed by wordpress.

Is this way feasible and good to go with or is there another better way please suggest.

Comment: You'll use the pre_get_posts hook, which allows you to alter the current query.  In the callback function, add a conditional to see if the query is for a category.  If it is, check to see if there is a tags querystring value.  If there is, add a meta_query to include this tag.  Everything you need to know is here:  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/  and here:  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/